# Pull a user-defined season from a date?

Tags: microsoft-excel, date

So I want to pull a season from a date. I have a seasons table and it goes a little like this.

```
Jan = Low (low/mid/high = season)
feb = low
mar = low
apr = mid
may = mid
jun = high
jul = high
aug = high
sep = mid
oct = mid
nov = low
dec = low
```

What I want to do is to display a season from the date: 15/07/2016

All help is appreciated, thank you

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can easily do it with `VLOOKUP`, just insert a new column with column numbers, then use this formula:

`=VLOOKUP(MONTH(E2),A:C,3,FALSE)`

[image]